# Python - converting a series of unknown number of input() entries into a list or an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, input

[I'm taking an intro to python class online](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/8-remix/) and the site is designed to auto-enter input() data into the program that you write to resolve various python logic problems.

[Please see this page to see how the online class's tool uses input entries](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/visualize/#code=lis%20%3D%20%5B%27Text%27%2C%20%27in%27%2C%20%27the%27%2C%20%27middle!%27%2C%20%27END%27%5D%0Awidth%20%3D%2013%0Afor%20s1%20in%20lis%3A%0A%20%20%20%20L%20%3D%20len%28s1%29%0A%20%20%20%20periods_rtside%20%3D%20%28width%20-%20L%29%2F%2F2%0A%20%20%20%20periods_leftside%20%3D%20width%20-%20periods_rtside%20-%20L%0A%20%20%20%20periods_rt_str%20%3D%20%27.%27%20%2a%20periods_rtside%0A%20%20%20%20periods_left_str%20%3D%20%27.%27%20%2a%20periods_leftside%0A%20%20%20%20line1%20%3D%20periods_left_str%20%2B%20s1%20%2B%20periods_rt_str%0A%20%20%20%20if%20s1%20%3D%3D%20%27END%27%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0A%20%20%20%20print%28line1%29%0A%20%20%20%20)

For example the class randomly inputs the following:

```
30
centered
text
is
great
testing
is
great
for
python!
END
```

Obviously, I would have to convert the 30 to an int. How do I convert the rest into a usable list or array?

```
width = int(input())
lis = ['centered', 'text', 'is', 'great', 'END']
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You append an element to a list like name.append(element). And it seems you already know how to read input with input(). So what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to call `input` in a loop. Here's one way to do it:

```
lst = []
s = input()
while s != 'END':
    lst.append(s)
    s = input()
```

There are other options for how to set up the condition on the loop, but I think this is the most straight forward. If the calculation for when to stop looping were more complicated, an alternative design might be to make the loop unconditional (with `while True`) and then `break` if the right conditions were met.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list and read each string one by one, and add it to the list:

```
width=int(input())
lis=[]
tmp=''
while tmp!='END':
    tmp=input()       #receives a string, in python 3.0+
    lis.append(tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` method they provide you will return each line of the user input as it's called. For example, the following function prints each line of the input by calling input throughout a loop

```
for line in range(6):
   print(input())
```